# Cucumber Testing a Javascript Countdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm building a Rails app that has a kind of lottery feature on it, where n tickets are chosen as winners at the end of some time. The site has a javascript countdown which will fire an event when it reaches zero. This event will trigger the browser to check with the server if the user is a winner. I've got a Cucumber feature that reads as follows:

```
Feature: Notify Winners
  So that I can tell if I've won
  As an authenticated user
  I want to be notified if I've won when the countdown completes

  Scenario: I have a winning ticket
    Given I'm logged in
    And I have a winning ticket for today
    When I'm on the home page
    And the countdown completes
    Then I should see "congratulations"
```

At this point, I'm doubting this feature is written in a reasonable way. As far as I can tell, within Cucumber, there's no way for me to verify when the countdown actually completes (by listening for a JS event, for example).

Left as is, the "When the countdown completes" step definition is what I'm unsure how to define. Any pointers on how this feature could be better tested?

Comment: You might find [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/391-testing-javascript-with-phantomjs?autoplay=true) helpful.

Comment: As far as I know you need to open use capybara/selenium to test javascript features. It slows it down a little, but it works